# Retention of continuous-export exported artifact history in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer

How long does Kusto retain history of exported artifacts? So, considering a specific continuous-export entity has been running for several years, what is the oldest export detail that I can get using the following command:-

```
.show continuous-export ContinuousExportName exported-artifacts
```

The documentation doesn't specifically refer to any specific time period for which this history is retained, so it's not very clear. What is the safe assumption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuous export show-artifacts history is retained for 14 days.